# Why are my ServiceConnection methods never executed?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service, android-tabhost

this is the class that calls my Service:

```
public class TicketList extends ListActivity
{
private ArrayList<Tickets> alTickets = new ArrayList<Tickets>();
private boolean listCreated = false;
private static Drawable background = null;
private Resources res;
private Tickets ticket = null;
private TicketConnector localService;

/** 
 * Called when the activity is first created. 
 * 
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticketlist);

    if(!listCreated)
    {
        connectService();
        //populateList();

        res = getResources();
        background = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
        listCreated = true;
    }

    TicketAdapter StatisticsAdapter = new TicketAdapter(this, alTickets);
    setListAdapter(StatisticsAdapter);
}

/**
 * Populates the ListView.
 * This needs to be done once the Activity is created and if the menu entry refresh is hit.
 */
private void populateList()
{
    try
    {           
        String jsonString = localService.queryData(new String[] {"getTicketList"}, new String[] {"Offen"});
        //String jsonString = new TicketConnector().queryData(new String[] {"getTicketList"}, new String[] {"Offen"});

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray ticketArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("tickets");

        Tickets[] tickets = new Tickets[ticketArray.length()];
        for (int i=0;i<ticketArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject object = ticketArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("ticket");   

            ticket = new Tickets(object.getString("id"), object.getString("color"), object.getString("priority"));
            alTickets.add(ticket);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DayTrader", "Exception getting JSON data", e);
    }
}

private void connectService() 
{
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TicketConnector.class);
     bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

public void getData() 
{
     String s = localService.queryData(new String[] {"getTicketList"}, new String[] {"Offen"});
}

ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() 
{
     @Override
     public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) 
     {
         Toast.makeText(TicketList.this, "Service connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         localService = ((TicketConnector.LocalBinder)binder).getService();
         Log.i("INFO", "Service bound: TicketConnector");
     }

     @Override
     public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) 
     {
         Toast.makeText(TicketList.this, "Service disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         localService = null;
         Log.i("INFO", "Service unbound: TicketConnector");
     }
 };
}
```

And this is the service:

```
public class TicketConnector extends Service
{   
private SharedPreferences settings = null;

// This is the object that receives interactions from clients.  See
// RemoteService for a more complete example.
private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

private String username = null;
private String password = null;
private String server = null;
private String port = null;
private String urlStr = null;

private String result = null;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    settings = CMDBSettings.getSettings(this);
    username = settings.getString("username", "");
    password = settings.getString("password", "");
    server = settings.getString("server", "");
    port = settings.getString("serverport", "");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return binder;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{

}

public String queryData(String[] actions, String[] category)
{
    //http://localhost:8080/MobileCMDB/TicketListener?format=json&actions=getTicketList&ticketcategory=Open
    urlStr = "http://"+server+":"+port+"/MobileCMDB/TicketListener?format=";
    new jsonParser().execute(actions);

    return result;
}

abstract class BaseParser extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{   
    protected BaseParser(String format)
    {
        urlStr += format;
    }

    private String makeUrlString(String[] actions, String[] category)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(urlStr);
        for (int i=0;i<actions.length;i++)
        {
            sb.append("&actions=");
            sb.append(actions[i]);

            sb.append("&ticketcategory=");
            sb.append(category[i]);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    protected InputStream getData(String[] actions, String[] category) throws Exception
    {
        URI uri = new URI(makeUrlString(actions, category));

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");

        if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip"))
        {
            content = new GZIPInputStream(content);
        }

        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString)
    {
        result = jsonString;
    }   
}

private class jsonParser extends BaseParser
{
    public jsonParser()
    {
        super("json");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... actions) 
    {
        String[] category = new String[] {"Open"};

        StringBuilder json = null;
        try
        {
            json = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getData(actions, category)));
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                json.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("PrimeCMDB - Network", "Exception getting JSON data", e);
        }

        return json.toString();
    }
}

/**
 * Class for clients to access.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with
 * IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder 
{
    public TicketConnector getService() 
    {
        return TicketConnector.this;
    }
}
}
```

This are the two activities in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ticket.TicketList"
    android:label="@string/ticket"
/>
<service 
    android:name=".network.TicketConnector" 
    android:enabled="true"
/>
```

onServiceConnected is never executed. Did I miss something?

Here is the output of LogCat at verbose mode while activating the TicketList Activity:

```
09-28 23:22:11.420: INFO/ActivityManager(795): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=org.mw88.cmdb/.gui.TicketListActivity }
09-28 23:22:12.340: WARN/ActivityManager(795): Binding with unknown activity: android.os.BinderProxy@4410bf30
09-28 23:22:16.090: INFO/ActivityManager(795): Displayed activity org.mw88.cmdb/.gui.TicketListActivity: 4606 ms (total 4606 ms)
```

Comment: Is your `onCreate()` method ever finishing?

Comment: Yes, the onCreate() method TicketList finishes but I just noticed that the service doesn't seem to connect at all. Its onCreate() method is never executed :(

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat. Most likely, there is a message in there (warning or error) that will clue you in to what is going on.

Comment: Updated description: LogCat output for this activity

Comment: `startService()` is not being called, or there is more to your LogCat than what you have listed. Try replacing `getApplicationContext()` with `this`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you all for your Answers.

I found the question after searching Google for this log message:

```
Binding with unknown activity: android.os.BinderProxy
```

It seems that Android has a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2483) when using bindService to fill a TabSpec Activity!

The solution was pretty simple:
just replace **bindService** with **getApplicationContext().bindService**

Now it works perfectly ;-)

Comment: eh... They should have documented this somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is a bug.

In my opinion, that's because when you use the TabActivity, the child activities will be embedded in the parent (TabActivity) as more like a view with activity behavior, hence its context cannot serve as an actual context.

So for the workaround, you need to get and use the parent (using **getParent()**) or the application context (using **getApplicationContext()**) which can act as an "actual" context.

But again, this is just my opinion because I cannot provide any link to any documentation related to this one. :)